# Filter data using Dropdowns if some fields are optional in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am working on a project when users have 10 dropdowns select box to filter data. The problem is that the user might not use all the select box. So I want to include some if conditions in this part.

```
public function PostSearch()
{
    $eye_color         = Input::get('eye_color');
    $tattoos           = Input::get('tattoos');
    $piercings         = Input::get('piercings');
    ....
    $user = User::where([['eye_color',$eye_color],
                            ['tattoos',$tattoos],
                            ['piercings',$piercings]])->get();
     return $user;
}
```

How to use if condition in the query for input select or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$filters = [
    'eye_color' => Input::get('eye_color'),
    'tattoos' => Input::get('tattoos'),
    'piercings' => Input::get('piercings'),
];

$user = User::where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
    if ($filters['eye_color']) {
        $query->where('eye_color', '=', $filters['eye_color']);
    }

    if ($filters['tattoos']) {
        $query->where('tattoos', '=', $filters['tattoos']);
    }

    if ($filters['piercings']) {
        $query->where('piercings', '=', $filters['piercings']);
    }
})->get();

return $user;
```

Let me know it's working or not.

Comment: your answer is similar  to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938952/laravel-query-with-if-conditions but here give me an error undefined $index can you explain why

Comment: May be there are many times this type of question asked! So it's possible to have duplicates!